# Index of zero of a gradient vector field at a critical point

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, morse-theory

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold with a Morse function $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$. The zeroes of the gradient vector field of $f$ are the critical points of $f$.

> How do you show that a critical point of $f$ with Morse index $k$ is a zero of the gradient vector field with index $(-1)^k$?

**Update, 8/29:** If somebody has *something* they want to add as an answer, there are 50 points are on the table that will otherwise go to waste.

*Notes:*

1. *The latter index is the degree of the Gauss map $\partial B^n \to S^{n-1}$ defined by the vector field on the boundary of a small ball $B^n$ containing the zero, as in Poincaré-Hopf.*
2. *I'm looking for an argument that is intrinsic or at least preserves the Riemannian structure, maybe using the Hessian. (Here's a sketch of my unsatisfying argument: Any two Riemannian structures on $M$ define gradient vector fields for $f$ with the same critical points, and you can define a time-dependent flow connecting any two such vector fields to see that the index of every zero is preserved. Thus it suffices to invoke the Morse lemma and use a Morse chart to pull back to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard Riemannian metric. From there, the claim is a simple, explicit calculation.)*

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something subtle but locally, a function of Morse index $k$ "looks like" $f(x)=-x_1^2-\ldots -x_k^2 + x_{k+1}^2+\ldots$ in suitable coordinates and the gradient of $f$ looks like $(-2x_1,\ldots, -2x_k,2x_{k+1}\ldots)$ in that coordinates. What is the degree of a *linear* map with a positive resp. negative determinant?

Comment: @PeterFranek: That works, essentially. But the gradient you've written down is the gradient with respect to the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$, whereas it should really be computed with respect to the metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ as pulled back from $M$ (because we're really studying a specificied gradient field).  You can get around that by showing that any two gradient vector fields indices agree at a critical point of $f$. There's an argument for that in one of the previous versions of the post, I think.  So I'm looking for something a bit more direct or intrinsic, for lack of a better word.

Comment: I know this is not completely formal but you can consider a neighborhood of $0$ small enough and a linear homtopy between the Euclidean and the pullback metric will induce a homotopy between the linear vector field and the pullback vector field...

Comment: @PeterFranek: Absolutely, that's the spirit of the argument I had in mind. I'm looking to see if there's an argument that leaves the metric alone, if it's possible to "see" the index of the zero of the vector field using the Hessian or something else.